QMK Static declaration follows non static
I'm trying to compile this code for a keyboard, but I keep getting this error message and I'm not sure what the issue is.
Error:
Compiling: quantum/keymap_introspection.c
                            quantum/keymap_introspection.c: In function 'encoder_update_user':
quantum/keymap_introspection.c:19:9: error: static declaration of 'keymap_layer_count_raw' follows non-static declaration
   19 | uint8_t keymap_layer_count_raw(void) {
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

quantum/keymap_introspection.c:23:31: error: static declaration of 'keymap_layer_count' follows non-static declaration

quantum/keymap_introspection.c:33:10: error: static declaration of 'keycode_at_keymap_location_raw' follows non-static declaration
   33 | uint16_t keycode_at_keymap_location_raw(uint8_t layer_num, uint8_t row, uint8_t column) {
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

quantum/keymap_introspection.c:40:32: error: static declaration of 'keycode_at_keymap_location' follows non-static declaration

.c file:
// Copyright 2022 Nick Brassel (@tzarc)
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0-or-later

// Pull the actual keymap code so that we can inspect stuff from it
#include KEYMAP_C

// Allow for keymap or userspace rules.mk to specify an alternate location for the keymap array
#ifdef INTROSPECTION_KEYMAP_C
#    include INTROSPECTION_KEYMAP_C
#endif // INTROSPECTION_KEYMAP_C

#include "keymap_introspection.h"

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Key mapping

#define NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW ((uint8_t)(sizeof(keymaps) / ((MATRIX_ROWS) * (MATRIX_COLS) * sizeof(uint16_t))))

uint8_t keymap_layer_count_raw(void) {
    return NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW;
}

__attribute__((weak)) uint8_t keymap_layer_count(void) {
    return keymap_layer_count_raw();
}

#ifdef DYNAMIC_KEYMAP_ENABLE
_Static_assert(NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW <= MAX_LAYER, "Number of keymap layers exceeds maximum set by DYNAMIC_KEYMAP_LAYER_COUNT");
#else
_Static_assert(NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW <= MAX_LAYER, "Number of keymap layers exceeds maximum set by LAYER_STATE_(8|16|32)BIT");
#endif

uint16_t keycode_at_keymap_location_raw(uint8_t layer_num, uint8_t row, uint8_t column) {
    if (layer_num < NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW && row < MATRIX_ROWS && column < MATRIX_COLS) {
        return pgm_read_word(&keymaps[layer_num][row][column]);
    }
    return KC_TRNS;
}

__attribute__((weak)) uint16_t keycode_at_keymap_location(uint8_t layer_num, uint8_t row, uint8_t column) {
    return keycode_at_keymap_location_raw(layer_num, row, column);
}


We need a [mcve]. Something that we can copy/paste into a compiler and reproduce the issue/error.

I'm very new to C++ but would this be enough:
uint8_t keymap_layer_count_raw(void) {
    return NUM_KEYMAP_LAYERS_RAW;
}

__attribute__((weak)) uint8_t keymap_layer_count(void) {
    return keymap_layer_count_raw();
}


You can test your program here. If your program produces the said error here, then you can copy/paste that code here by editing your question.

We can only suspect that the (pretty odd) #includes that precede the function contain some errors. The compiler realizes this when the function declaration doesn't match what it has seen before,

Also, this looks like C code. Compiling C as C++ can also cause a few extra surprises. As can writing a  program in more than one language. Not something a beginner ought to get involved in.

Is that your own code? Or some existing code? A good start with QMK is to first compile code that is known to be compilable.

You need to provide more context (so we can reproduce the problem). For example, how do start the compilation? What command line invocation is used?

It may be caused by something outside the code. For example, Git submodules not having been loaded.

A good first step is to compile some other existing keyboard. For example, Keychron V6 with the commandline qmk compile -kb keychron/v6/iso_encoder -km via. This should always succeed. Otherwise, there is probably something wrong with setting up the QMK development environment.

What Git repository did you use? The official QMK repository? Or more other repository?

Here is a Reddit post with the same error messages.

The keymap_introspection.h / keymap_introspection.c is part of a larger whole. Where is it located?

keymap_introspection.h and keymap_introspection.c are part the core QMK (/quantum/keymap_introspection.h and /quantum/keymap_introspection.c). Thus they are expected to work. The problem is somewhere else, e.g., in the Git repository state, how compilation is invoked, required dependencies for the development environment (e.g., if they are installed or has the correct version), etc.

What operating system? In what environment is QMK set up?
